# Panel grid alignment in jsf 1.2

Tags: datatable, panel, vertical-alignment, jsf-1.2

I am having problem in aligning data tables inside a panel grid. Always data table is getting aligned in the center instead of the top. 'vertical-align:text-top;' CSS class also not working.

Comment: ya got the answer `.panelColumns td {
    vertical-align: top; 
}` is working fine. :-)

Comment: Just put it as a answer (below) and clic it as the good one (green mark at the left).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya got the answer `.panelColumns td { vertical-align: top; }` is working fine. :-)